# Diretiva de máscara em Angular 2 não coloca a máscara ao iniciar a tela

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Olá, fiz uma diretiva no `Angular 2` para colocar máscaras em alguns campos, um deles o de CEP. Funciona certinho, a única coisa que eu não consegui fazer ainda é que ao carregar os dados nos campos da tela o valor fique com a máscara, ela só funciona quando o foco está no campo que tem a diretiva.

Já tentei colocar vários eventos em host, mas nenhum funcionou, já tentei usar `change`, `input`, mas nenhum deu certo.

Abaixo segue o código `HTML` com o `input` que tem a diretiva, o nome da diretiva é cep:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group fg-line">
        <label for="cep">CEP</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cep" placeholder="CEP" required [(ngModel)]="empresa.Cep" borda-animada
            cep maxlength="9" ngControl="cep" #cep="ngForm">
    </div>
</div>
```

Agora abaixo o código da diretiva:

```
import {Directive} from '@angular/core';
import {NgModel} from '@angular/common';
import {Mascaras} from '../core/mascaras'

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel][cep]',
    providers: [NgModel],
    host: {
        '(blur)': 'onInputChange($event)',
        '(input)': 'onInputChange($event)'
    }
})
export class CepDirective {
    modelValue: string;
    viewValue: string;

constructor(public model: NgModel) {
}

onInputChange(event) {
    console.log('teste ngmodelchange');

    //event é o evento html que é disparado no evento blur
    //por isso precisa pegar o target.value.
    var newValue = Mascaras.cep(event.target.value);
    this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(newValue);       
}
}
```